# Jquery click listener not firing (html,css,jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this script in the head of the html:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
    $(function () {
        $('.nav-toggle').on('click',function(){
            $('.mainnav').toggleClass('open');
        });
    });
</script>
```

which should fire when:

```
<header>
    <img class="nav-toggle" src="static/images/menunav.png" style="cursor: pointer;">
</header>
```

this image is clicked.

and toggle the subclass open in:

```
<ul class="text mainnav">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Projects</li>
        <li>Techniques</li>
        <li>About me</li>
    </ul>
```

But it wont fire the .open class? What am i doing wrong here (first time jquery user).

CSS:

```
.nav-toggle {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 70px;
}

    .mainnav{
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: #222;
      text-align: center;
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
      transform: translateX(-100%);
      transition: transform 0.6s ease;
    }

    .mainnav.open {
      transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

Comment: Seems to work just fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/syuqmyr1/

Comment: Yeah, it works.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to wait for `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem is in the html.
Try to split

```
<script src="[JQuery CDN]"></script>
<script>
$(function(){ ... });
</script>
```